# Want file in CSV. I need a Regex to change a space to a comma on each line EXCEPT the Description Field which should remain with a space

Tags: google-sheets, regex-replace

**Goal:**

I want a CSV file as my result. I want to change the space char to a comma on each line of data.  BUT, I also need the data for the 3rd field (Description) to remain as is with original space chars.  Each line of data is terminated with a newline char.

Flipping spaces to commas on every line is easy with regex.  But how do 'bookend' the string of text which will then become the 3rd/Description field and preserve its spaces?  Currently I manually change commas back to spaces just in that text string.  Painful.

**Example of Final result needed (including column names)**

```
Transaction Date,Posting Date,Description,Reference Number,Account Number,Amount

12/23,12/24,GOOGLE*DOMAINS SUPPORT.GOOGLCA,7811,8550,12.00
```

**My sample data:**

```
12/23 12/24 GOOGLE*DOMAINS SUPPORT.GOOGLCA 7811 8550 12.00

01/02 01/04 CREPEVINE - OAKLAND OAKLAND 234567 CA 1087 8220 16.32

01/06 01/07 AB* ABEBOOKS.CO J6YDBX HTTPSWWW.ABEBWA 6289 85332 6.98

01/20 01/21 SQ *BAGEL STREET CAFE Oakland CA 2313 44444 24.43
```

**A few of My Regex attempts**

- This cmd changes spaces to commas over all 5 lines by combining it with Join cmd. Easy.

And just fyi: "\n" would not work for some reason so I do the <Ctrl+Enter> keys to inject a newline char, ie the two lines.  For now it orks fine.

```
=regexreplace(join("

",A1:A5)," ",",")


RESULT:
12/23,12/24,GOOGLE*DOMAINS,SUPPORT.GOOGLCA,7811,8550,12.00
...
01/02,01/04,CREPEVINE,-,OAKLAND,OAKLAND,CA,1087,8550,16.32
...
```

- Here is my poor attemp to bookend the description field, then flip commas back to spaces, but no luck either.

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A1,"(,[A-Z]+[A-Z],)"," ")
```

How do I craft a regex to do this?
cheers,
Damon

[Using Regex101 to reverse learn how you did it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2RnF.png)

Comment: Also, I am doing this in Google sheets.  I've read a bit about 'lookaheads' in regex as a part of this solution.  But I also read the Sheets does not support lookaheads.  If true, then maybe post solutions that avoid this.  I'm open to all advice cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try:

```
=index(if(len(A:A),regexreplace(A:A,"(?U)(.*) (.*) (.*) (\d[^A-Za-z]*) (\d.*) (\d.*)","$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6"),))
```

[image]

Comment: I'm beside myself :-).  I just read about "re.U" for the (?U).  Have no clue what this means.   The sample data is from a PDF bank statement (b/c they don't supply CSV files, go figure).  And I need to get all 12 months of transactions into CSV so I can Import into Quickbooks.  This will save me Time & money in not having to pay a bookkeeper for data entry.  You're amazing.

Comment: To try & understand your logic & regex, I ran it thru regex101 & included a screenshot.  Use the link above or  here  [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2RnF.png)

Comment: What I don't get is groups 2 & 3. Did you break the string into 2 parts?  Also,  when you write out the groups (ie $1...$6) how does $2 & $3 not show a comma(,) between them even though its there in the regex field?

Comment: the first 2 capturing groups `(.*) (.*)` capture `Transaction Date,Posting Date`; the 3rd one `(.*)` for `description` is warranted to extend & capture till the point it encounters the next group (`reference number`) which starts with a numbers & no alphabets detected beyond that `(\d[^A-Za-z]*)`

Comment: Ah I follow now.  Thanks so much for explaining.

Comment: -Need a little help again for slightly diff use case.  This time I want ONLY the 3rd (Description) field, and ignore all else. Also I now found numerics in field so need to handle that also Sample Data:
```
12/23 12/24 GOOGLE*DOMAINS SUPPORT.GOOGLCA 7811 8550 12.00
01/04 01/06 KAISER CPP PHARM 256 8882186245 CA 2874 8550 20.00
```
** Wanted result **
```
GOOGLE*DOMAINS SUPPORT.GOOGLCA
KAISER CPP PHARM 256 8882186245 CA
```
** My attempt **
```
=index(if(len(B5:B16),regexreplace(B5:B16,"(?U)(.*) (.*) (.*?[A-Za-z0-9]{2}) (\d.*) (\d.*)","$3"),))
```

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/IBec6Rv.png please try: `=index(if(len(A:A),regexextract(A:A,".*? .*? (.*) \d+ \d+ \d+"),))`

Comment: You're amazing.  You make it look so simple.  I've tried so many extract & replaces.  Drinks on me!! Thanks, Damon